# I whould like to know haw to connect with OLEDB in SSIS Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, oledbconnection

When I try to connect with OLEDB Connection

### I get  this notifications message : TITLE: Connection Manager

The specified provider is not supported. Please choose different provider in connection manager.

I need Solution to solve this problem